# Inner join with mysql not works

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys  am new to mysql development and am trying to inner join my both tables ..My code

```
SELECT Customers.name, oop.id
FROM Customers(SELECT name,id FROM Orders) AS oop
INNER JOIN oop
ON Customers.name=oop.id
ORDER BY Customers.name;
```

When i tried this code it shows me error i know this can be easily done with other method but i have seen this method on a website so i tried..Am i doing any error in my code.

Hope you guys can help me out ..Any help would be appreciated ..Thanx

Comment: What you want just explain and give table schema for further help

Comment: i just want to innerjoin my table .is the procedure right ??

Comment: why do you need subselect? why not SELECT Customers.name, Orders.id FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.name = Orders.id ...

Comment: @user3777677 have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a wrong syntax. it would be somthing like this:-

```
SELECT Customers.name, oop.id
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN (SELECT name,id FROM Orders) AS oop
ON Customers.name=oop.id
ORDER BY Customers.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need the second select (although you can use it as Ankit Bajpai's answer shows).

```
SELECT Customers.name, oop.id
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN orders as oop
ON Customers.name=oop.id
ORDER BY Customers.name;
```

Comment: i have just used second select to filfil the user's desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try If your relationship is correct with table.

```
SELECT Customers.name, oop.id
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN orders as oop
ON Customers.name=oop.id
ORDER BY Customers.name;
```